# jQuery after() not working with dynamically created node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a WYSIWYG text editor and can't use `.on` instead `<a onclick>`, because then I lose text selection. But I need to insert `<div>` after dynamically created node.

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="wrap('div')">
    <div class = "insert_after" ></div>
</a>
```

JS

```
function wrap(tag) {
  var sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var selectedText = range.toString();
        range.deleteContents();
        var newNode = document.createElement(tag);
        range.insertNode(newNode);
        $(newNode).after("<div style = 'width: 100%; min-height: 20px'></div>");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `.after()` works for me on a dynamically inserted element: http://jsfiddle.net/q61ucmck/ you sure the problem doesn't come before that line?

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing :

```
var newNode = document.createElement(tag);
range.insertNode(newNode);
```

by :

```
var newNode = $('<'+tag+'></'+tag+'>');
range.insertNode(newNode[0]);
```